# How to resolve 'calls' does not exist on type '() => any'

Tags: typescript, jasmine

Testing my angular2 app.  I try and set a spy and then check how many times it has been called.  I keep getting this TS error though

> Property 'calls' does not exist on type '() => any'.

***How Do I resolve this error?***

```
describe('ssh Service', () => {
    let ref:SshRefService;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [
                { provide: SshRefService, useClass: refClass },
            ]
        });

    });

    beforeEach(inject([SshRefService], (sshRef:SshRefService) => {
        ref = sshRef
        spyOn(ref, 'getClient').and.returnValue(true)
    }));

    it('should mock an observable', () => {
        //service.list() calls ref.getClient() internally
        expect(service.list('/share')).toEqual(Observable.of(mockFileList));

        expect(ref.getClient.calls.count()).toBe(1);


    });
});
```

Comment: Try to do `expect((ref.getClient as any).calls.count()).toBe(1);`

Comment: Where is `SshRefService` defined? How do you import it?

Answer (score 8):

It looks like `SshRefService` currently defines `getClient() : any`. As a result, it's correctly throwing this error. This is happening because the mocking process replaces the property/method with the Spy, but Typescript has no way of knowing that's taken place.

Since you've spied on `SshRefService.getClient` , you have two ways to test whether it's been called:

`spyOn` returns a `jasmine.Spy` object, which exposes the calls property directly. You can save the result of `spyOn(ref, 'getClient').and.returnValue(true)` on the example object, and then test that like so:

```
expect(getClientSpy.calls.count()).toEqual(1)
```

Preferred (probably): You can run expect on the method on the object itself, like so:

```
expect(ref.getClient).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to another answer, but you can type directly to a spy

```
expect((ref.getClient as jasmine.Spy).calls.count()).toBe(1);
```