# Property 'xxxx' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am debugging a code I have not written, and I am new to typescript. I am getting a TS2339 error

> Property 'InputFiles' does not exist on type '{}'.
>   I understand that this means that I am missing to hand-over the property, 
>   but what should I modify?

Within `UI\src\containers\FileUploaderContainer.tsx`, I have something like

```js
export class FileUploader extends React.Component<any, any> {
    render() {
        return ( <div><UploadFileFormContainer /></div> );
    }
}

const FileUploaderContainer: { any } = connect(
    state => ({ InputFiles: state.InputFiles }),  // error occurs here
    dispatch => ({})
)(FileUploader);

export default FileUploaderContainer;
```

#### Background

If I hover in Visual Studio above `connect`, I see

```
(alias) connect<{InputFiles: any;}, any, {}, {}>(mapStateToProps: MapStateToPropsParam<{
InputFIles: any; }, {}, {}>, mapDispatchToProps: MapDispatchToPropsNonObject<any,{}>):
InterferableComponentEnhancerWithPropos<any,{}> (+ 14 overloads)
import connect
```

#### Related questions

The following issues did not help me to resolve my issue

- [Typescript property does not exist on type {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49467069/)
- [Property 'xxx' does not exist on type '{}'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51377151/property-xxx-does-not-exist-on-type)
- [property 'update' does not exist on type '{}'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52051108/property-update-does-not-exist-on-type)
- [Property 'xxxx' does not exist on type '{ [key: string]: AbstractControl; }'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43066538/property-xxxx-does-not-exist-on-type-key-string-abstractcontrol)
- [How to resolve 'calls' does not exist on type '() => any'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42259813/how-to-resolve-calls-does-not-exist-on-type-any#42261590)
- [Property 'keys' does not exist on type 'any[]'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49566156/property-keys-does-not-exist-on-type-any)
- [Property does not exists on type '{}' using Promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49854385/)

Comment: Well, your `state` is (somehow) defined as being `{}`, so TS doesn't know of any properties on it.

Comment: @VLAZ May you be so kind and guide me here? I am assuming that I should replace one of the `any`? I still not too comfortable  with the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)...

Comment: @Pac0 May you elaborate a bit, please? Do you mean I should add an `as any` at the very end?

Comment: what is the type definition for first argument of your connect function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may just add `any` type for the state like this:

```
const FileUploaderContainer : any = connect(
  (state : any ) => ({ InputFiles: state.InputFiles }),  // just add any type on state
  dispatch => ({})
)(FileUploader);
```